# resetStateMachine does not clear its id

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am using a pooled list of `StateMachine` instances (at present limited to one) and am switching the context that `statemachine` is working with - however the `StateMachine ID` is never updated and I end up overwriting my `statemachine` in the db when i try to persist. More info on how below as well as the question.

My question is why upon calling `resetStateMachine` (in `AbstractStateMachine.java`) with a null context (ie trying to create a new context) does this not clear out the current id of the machine (I understand why `UUID` stays - that is unique to the machine) but id relates to the context also, no? If the context is not null it tries to pull the id from the `stateMachineContext`

Extracts of relevant sources:

If context is null:

```
log.info("Got null context, resetting to initial state and clearing extended state");
this.currentState = this.initialState;
this.extendedState.getVariables().clear();
```

If context is not null:

```
this.setId(stateMachineContext.getId());
```

When I later call persist.restore to pull back a state machine context this means I have an old id present and end up overwriting rather than using a new id to persist with.

This is using currently released version 1.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, don't see any reason why we would not clear `id` as well if null context is passed. Would you mind creating a github issue to track that change request?